# Github's electron doesn't allow embed tags?

Tags: html, github, electron

Is there some sort of restriction? The console doesn't show any errors.

I am attempting to display a pdf using basic embed tags:

```
<embed src="./someFile.pdf" width="500" height="375" type='application/pdf'>
```

but my electron application shows:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Electron uses Chromium under the hood and I don't believe Chromium is bundled with a PDF viewer plugin like Chrome is. You would need to recompile Electron with the proper plugins. There are also some Javascript PDF viewers out there you may want to look into.

[PDF.js](https://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/) appears to be a solid choice and indeed [another Electron user](https://discuss.atom.io/t/pdf-plugin-in-electron-app/19186) appears to be using it to solve your exact problem :)

Good luck!